# Is there anyway to create an if statement to print an output that says by how many kilos i have exceeded?

Tags: c, if-statement

Also is it possible for the for the kilos to be measured by exactly 0.5kg? For example the maximum weight of an object is 20kg however I input an object that is 22.5 kg. So the output would be "You have exceeded by 2.5 kg.". Also is it possible vice versa( Input=15 kg, Output=You have not achieved the minimum weight. You are short of x kg ). And is it also possible for the distance? Example the minimum distance is 10 km and the maximum distance is 2000 km but I input x km which is either less than 10 km  or more than 2000 km. The output would be "Your distance is less/more by y km."

---

```
#include <stdio.h>   //standard i/o
#include <math.h>   //roundoff

//Do not accept package’s weight less than 2 kg or more than 20 kg. And do not accept
//distance less than 10 km or more than 2000 km. These are the company’s policies.

int main()
{
    float weight, charges, rate;
    int distance;

    printf("Enter weight in kg: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &weight);

    printf("Shipping in distance in km: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &distance);

    if (weight < 2 || weight > 20 || distance < 10 || distance > 2000)
    {
        printf("The minimum weight is 2kg and the maximum weight is 20kg.\nThe minimum distance is 10km and the maximum distance is 2000km.");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (weight < 6)
    {
        rate = 2.2;
    }
    else if (weight < 10)
    {
        rate = 3.7;
    }
    else
    {
        rate = 4.8;
    }

    charges = (weight * rate);
    printf("Charges for %f", weight);
    printf(" kg and shipping distance of %d", distance);
    printf(" km are : RM%f", charges);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Rorschach 
1.When I try to paste the code it says it's not formatted properly.
2.I have been trying the past day but I am not great with if statements.
3.Well I sure as hell dont know how to.

Comment: You can just calculate the numbers you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple actually . Use if statement separately for both increase or decrease in weight or distance.i.e

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int distance;
    float weight;
    printf("Enter weight in kg:\n");
    scanf("%f",&weight);
    printf("Shipping in distance in km:\n");
    scanf("%d",&distance);
    if(weight>=20)
    {
        printf("you have exceeded by %f kg\n",weight-20);
    }
    else if(weight<=2)
    {
        printf("You have not achieved the minimum weight. You are short of %f kg\n",2-weight);    
    }
    if(distance>=2000)
    {
        printf("Your distance is more by %d km\n",distance-2000);
    }
    else if(distance<=10)
    {
        printf("Your distance is less by %d km\n",10-distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. However is there a way to implement your code while retaining this part of the code: if (weight < 2 || weight > 20 || distance < 10 || distance > 2000)
    {
        printf("The minimum weight is 2kg and the maximum weight is 20kg.\nThe minimum distance is 10km and the maximum distance is 2000km.");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (weight < 6)
    {
        rate = 2.2;
    }
    else if (weight < 10)
    {
        rate = 3.7;
    }
    else
    {
        rate = 4.8;
    }

Comment: use another if statement for that purpose.  and accept the answer or vote it if you like the answer..